# No EdgeSync credentials were found for Edge Transport

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I've three exchange servers, 1 edge, and two mailbox servers and while running the command test-edgesubcription I'm getting the below error on one mailbox server.

I've checked the bundle of articles, and I've taken the following steps as well.
Delete the subscription from edge and mailbox, and delete the local certificates from all 3 servers
and create the new certificates via  "new-exchangecertificate command" and regenerate the EdgeSubscription but still, one mailbox server is giving the below error.
Network connectivity, name resolution, ping everything is fine. Expert opinion is required.
EdgeSync service cannot connect to this subscription because of the error "No EdgeSync
credentials were found for Edge Transport server EXC02 on the local
Mailbox server. Remove the Edge subscription and re-subscribe the Edge Transport
server.".

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed.
somehow exchange server was not using the newly created certificate, I found this in the event viewer after services restarted. not sure about the event viewer ID but the event was similar to the one below
"The certificate with thumbprint XXXXXXXXX was not found either restore the certificate or create new. use this command to enable the certificate Enble-Exchangecertificate  -smtp "
after that, i compare the thumbprint from the log and certificate store. then i enable the certificate with the below command.

Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint  -Services SMTP
Or you could share the result running the command:

Get-ExchangeCertificate | fl

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/911472/no-edgesync-credentials-were-found-for-edge-transp.html